# Why WP_Screeen doesn't show all options with admin_body_class

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu, sub-menu

I was trying to add a specific class to the admin section. I created a new top-level menu page and now I want to add a specific class to this top-level menu and its submenu items.

What I have tried so far is that I used `WP_Screen` to get the data of the current screen.

If I check the submenu page and I did `var_dump(get_current_screen())`. It shows every detail.

But now the case is that If I use `get_current_screen()` with `admin_body_class` why it doesn't work.

As far as I know, the hook is early called before the submenu page details are loaded.

Now I want to ask, how it is possible to check if the submenu has a specific parent base,

Here is the code that I tried so far.

```
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'tw_admin_body_class');
function tw_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    var_dump($screen);
    if (  $screen->parent_base == 'tw-top' )  {
        return $classes . ' raashid';
    }
}
```

But `parent_base` is set to null. Any idea how to add class to submenu pages if it is under the specific top-level menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But `parent_base` is set to null.

Yes, because by the time `admin_body_class` is fired, WordPress hasn't yet set the `parent_base` value.

And it's only set *after* the `<body>` tag is actually outputted. More specifically, it's set only after the `<div id="wpbody" role="main">` as you can see [here in `wp-admin/admin-header.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L263).

> Any idea how to add class to submenu pages if it is under the specific top-level menu.

You can use the `admin_body_class` hook, but instead of the `$screen->parent_base`, use `$screen->id` which is the hook name returned by `add_menu_page()` as well as `add_submenu_page()`.

And to get that hook name, you should or would want to use [`get_plugin_page_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hook/).

So for example:

- If I added my top-level and sub menus like so:

  ```php
  // Top-level menu: "Test menu"
  add_menu_page( 'Test', 'Test menu', 'manage_options', 'test', 'some_function' );

  // Submenu: "Test submenu"
  add_submenu_page( 'test', 'Submenu Page', 'Test submenu', 'manage_options',
      'test-submenu', 'some_function_2' );
  ```
- Then I can add the custom CSS class like so:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'my_admin_body_class' );
  function my_admin_body_class( $classes ) {
      $screen = get_current_screen();

      if ( get_plugin_page_hook( 'test', '' ) === $screen->id ) {
          $classes .= ' foo-class';
      }
      elseif ( get_plugin_page_hook( 'test-submenu', 'test' ) === $screen->id ) {
          $classes .= ' bar-class';
      }

      return $classes; // *always return this
  }
  ```

  Note that I emphasized the `return $classes;` because in your `tw_admin_body_class()` function, the `$classes` is only returned if your conditional returns a true.

And actually, the plugin page hook is added by default to the `<body>` tag of the menu/admin page as well as the *top-level* menu item (`<li>` tag), e.g. `<body class="... toplevel_page_test ...">` on my "Test" admin page, so you could probably just make use of that class?

Comment: thanks for your help. I have a specific need to add body class. Otherwise, I knew the CSS option exists. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: In that case, then I removed the CSS code, but I retained the "make use of that class" part. :)